# Cannot call methods remotely

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, rmi, jndi

Hello I am new to RMI and Glassfish and needs help with this.

My sample code:

```
package test.JNDITest;

import javax.ejb.Remote;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Remote
public interface Foo extends Serializable {

    public int testMethod(int number);
    public MyNewObject createMyNewObject();
}

package test.JNDITest;

import java.io.Serializable;

public interface MyNewObject extends Serializable{
    public void testMethod2();
}

package test.JNDITest;

import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class FooImpl implements Foo{
    @Override
    public int testMethod(int number) {
        return number + 1000;
    }

    @Override
    public MyNewObject createMyNewObject() {
        return new MyNewObjectImpl();
    }
}

package test.JNDITest;

public class MyNewObjectImpl implements MyNewObject {

    @Override
    public void testMethod2() {
    }
}
```

I package this and deploy on Glassfish 3. Now I try to test it:

```
import test.JNDITest.Foo;
import test.JNDITest.MyNewObject;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import java.util.Properties;

public class TestMath {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");

        Context context = new InitialContext(properties);

        Foo x = (Foo) context.lookup("java:global/JNDITest-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/JNDITest-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/FooImpl!test.JNDITest.Foo");
        System.out.println(x.testMethod(42));

        MyNewObject x2 = x.createMyNewObject();
    }
}
```

testMethod works fine but when I use createMyNewObject I have:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.RemoteException: CORBA NO_IMPLEMENT 1398079489 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT: WARNING: IOP01000001: Missing local value implementation  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 1 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy134.missingLocalValueImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.FVDCodeBaseImpl.implementation(FVDCodeBaseImpl.java:113)
    at com.sun.org.omg.SendingContext._CodeBaseImplBase._invoke(_CodeBaseImplBase.java:99)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1624)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1486)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.JNDITest.MyNewObjectImpl (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:375)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:165)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:135)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.JDKBridge.loadClassM(JDKBridge.java:319)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.JDKBridge.loadClass(JDKBridge.java:228)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.loadClass(Util.java:640)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.RepositoryId.getClassFromType(RepositoryId.java:577)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.getClassFromType(ValueHandlerImpl.java:373)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.FVDCodeBaseImpl.implementation(FVDCodeBaseImpl.java:105)
    ... 12 more

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 1 completed: Maybe
    at test.JNDITest._Foo_Wrapper.createMyNewObject(test/JNDITest/_Foo_Wrapper.java)
    at TestMath.main(TestMath.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: CORBA NO_IMPLEMENT 1398079489 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT: WARNING: IOP01000001: Missing local value implementation  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 1 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy134.missingLocalValueImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.FVDCodeBaseImpl.implementation(FVDCodeBaseImpl.java:113)
    at com.sun.org.omg.SendingContext._CodeBaseImplBase._invoke(_CodeBaseImplBase.java:99)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1624)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1486)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.JNDITest.MyNewObjectImpl (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:375)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:165)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:135)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.JDKBridge.loadClassM(JDKBridge.java:319)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.JDKBridge.loadClass(JDKBridge.java:228)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.loadClass(Util.java:640)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.RepositoryId.getClassFromType(RepositoryId.java:577)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.getClassFromType(ValueHandlerImpl.java:373)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.FVDCodeBaseImpl.implementation(FVDCodeBaseImpl.java:105)
    ... 12 more

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 1 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:311)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:227)
    at test.JNDITest.__Foo_Remote_DynamicStub.createMyNewObject(test/JNDITest/__Foo_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT: WARNING: IOP01000001: Missing local value implementation  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 1 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy134.missingLocalValueImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.FVDCodeBaseImpl.implementation(FVDCodeBaseImpl.java:113)
    at com.sun.org.omg.SendingContext._CodeBaseImplBase._invoke(_CodeBaseImplBase.java:99)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1624)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1486)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.JNDITest.MyNewObjectImpl (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:375)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:165)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:135)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.JDKBridge.loadClassM(JDKBridge.java:319)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.JDKBridge.loadClass(JDKBridge.java:228)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.loadClass(Util.java:640)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.RepositoryId.getClassFromType(RepositoryId.java:577)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.getClassFromType(ValueHandlerImpl.java:373)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.FVDCodeBaseImpl.implementation(FVDCodeBaseImpl.java:105)
    ... 12 more

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 1 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.MessageBase.getSystemException(MessageBase.java:900)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.ReplyMessage_1_2.getSystemException(ReplyMessage_1_2.java:131)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.getSystemExceptionReply(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:637)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.processResponse(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:499)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:373)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.invoke(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:273)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(ObjectImpl.java:457)
    at com.sun.org.omg.SendingContext._CodeBaseStub.implementation(_CodeBaseStub.java:63)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CachedCodeBase.implementation(CachedCodeBase.java:119)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.getClassFromString(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:2292)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1095)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:384)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readResult(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:483)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:203)
    ... 10 more
```

This is my first post please be gentle :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `MyNewObjectImpl` class needs to extend `UnicastRemoteObject`, or be exported some other way. At the moment it isn't a remote object at all, as it isn't exported, so it is being serialized to the Registry and the client, which isn't what you want at all.